# the problem of using "~\\" and blank line

Tags: warnings

Recently,I found the code that cotains the`"~\\"` and `blank line` always shows the warning imformation "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines"

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\hfuzz=\maxdimen


$(A \pm  B)^{-1} \neq A^{-1} \pm B^{-1}$,$(A \pm  B)^* \neq A^* \pm B^*$~\\

$|(A^*)^*|=|A|^{n^2-2 n+1}$~\\

\end {document}
```

I add the code:

```
\tolerance=10000
\hbadness=10000
\begin{document}
```

However,fail to solve it!

Comment: This is an _exact_ duplicate of your question a few hours earlier. Please do not do that. If you need to clarify a question _edit the question_.

Comment: I've duped the older question to this one: as David says, please don't simply repeat the same question.

Comment: @Joseph Wright♦ ,Oh thanks for your suggestion,I see!

Comment: @David Carlisle,Ok,I see and thanks sincerely!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A paragraph should be ended by leaving a blank line in the input, not with `~\\`. What happens is that an empty line is produced and it's underfull by construction, because it has nothing in it.

If you really need a blank line between two paragraph, use `\bigskip` (better yet `\medskip`) between them:

```
... this is the end of a paragraph.

\bigskip % or \medskip

Here a new one starts ...
```

If you want a vertical space between *all* paragraphs, consider loading instead the `parskip` package (look at its documentation). Note that “leaving blank lines” here and there is a practice coming from the usage of word processors, where it's very easy to do it (and thus spoil the document's appearance).

For your formulas, you should use an alignment environment; if you want (almost) flush left equations, there's the option `fleqn`:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gather*}
(A \pm  B)^{-1} \neq A^{-1} \pm B^{-1},\quad
(A \pm  B)^* \neq A^* \pm B^*\\
|(A^*)^*|=|A|^{n^2-2 n+1}
\end{gather*}
\lipsum*[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Warning

Use *none* of the following commands:

```
\hfuzz=\maxdimen
\tolerance=10000
\hbadness=10000
```

With them you're basically saying that you don't care about getting good paragraphs. Maybe you don't care, but your readers do.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of `~` is `\penalty \@M \`. This means that there is a space printed, and a penalty of `\@M`, or 10000, is assessed for breaking the line after the space. But you have forced TeX to break the line at that point with `\\`, so you are guaranteeing a warning.

Comment: ,How to avoid the warnnig and I want to yield a black line?